# URL Rewrite Redirect error

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-8

I am trying to get what should be a very simple URL redirect working in IIS 8 using URL Rewrite. I need to rewrite this URL:

http://test.asystyou.com/Restaurant/Made-Main-Street/1990-Main-St-112-Sarasota,-FL-34236/305

to this:

http://test.asystyou.com/Restaurant/Made-Main-Street/1990-Main-St-112-Sarasota,-FL-34236/30

I have written the rule at least 6 different ways and they all fail.

First version

```
<rule name="RestaurantDirect" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^http:\//test.asystyou.com\/Restaurant\/Made-Main-Street\/1990-Main-St-112-Sarasota,-FL-34236\/305$" />
  <conditions>
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://test.asystyou.com/Restaurant/Made-Main-Street/1990-Main-St-112-Sarasota,-FL-34236/30" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Second version

```
<rule name="RestaurantDirect" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^305$" />
  <conditions>
  <add input="{HTTP_POST}" pattern="^http:\//test.asystyou.com\/Restaurant\/Made-Main-Street\/1990-Main-St-112-Sarasota,-FL-34236\/$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://test.asystyou.com/Restaurant/Made-Main-Street/1990-Main-St-112-Sarasota,-FL-34236/30" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Third version

```
<rule name="RestaurantDirect" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^305$" />
  <conditions>
  <add input="{HTTP_POST}" pattern="^\/Restaurant\/Made-Main-Street\/1990-Main-St-112-Sarasota,-FL-34236\/$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="/Restaurant/Made-Main-Street/1990-Main-St-112-Sarasota,-FL-34236/30" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Fourth version

```
<rule name="RestaurantDirect" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^305$" />
  <conditions>
  <add input="{HTTP_POST}" pattern="^http:\//test.asystyou.com\/Restaurant\/Made-Main-Street\/1990-Main-St-112-Sarasota,-FL-34236\/$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="30" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Fifth version

```
<rule name="RestaurantDirect" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^305$" />
  <conditions>
  <add input="{HTTP_POST}" pattern="^http:\//test.asystyou.com\/Restaurant\/Made-Main-Street\/1990-Main-St-112-Sarasota,-FL-34236\/$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="{C:0}/30" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Sixth version

```
<rule name="RestaurantDirect" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^305$" />
  <conditions>
  <add input="{HTTP_POST}" pattern="^\/Restaurant\/Made-Main-Street\/1990-Main-St-112-Sarasota,-FL-34236\/$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="{C:0}/30" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Every one of these fail. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This rule will fork for you:

```
<rule name="RestaurantDirect" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="Restaurant/Made-Main-Street/1990-Main-St-112-Sarasota,-FL-34236/305$" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="/Restaurant/Made-Main-Street/1990-Main-St-112-Sarasota,-FL-34236/30"/>
</rule>
```

Comment: victor this works perfectly. out of the six scenarios i posted above, #1 is the closest to this. what caused that scenario not to work? was it because i included domain and did not need it? or did it have something to do with how i was escaping the special characters? maybe if i can understand where i was going wrong i can do these more effectively moving forward.

Comment: URL rewrite is comparing pattern inside `match url` with request path without starting slash. In your case request path is `Restaurant/Made-Main-Street/1990-Main-St-112-Sarasota,-FL-34236/305`. And your patter from  #1 `^http:\//test.asystyou.com\/Restaurant\/Made-Main-Street\/1990-Main-St-112-Sarasota,-FL-34236\/305$` doesn't have matches with this string `Restaurant/Made-Main-Street/1990-Main-St-112-Sarasota,-FL-34236/305`

Comment: ok that makes sense. thanks for the solution and for the explanation.